Postman GET Returns Successful but SwiftUI App GET Returns Decode Error
I am running a vapor server. My app network requests are all working perfectly except for getOrders. When running the request on Postman it returns successfully. Can anyone see what Postman does to get a response that I am failing to do?
This is the error I'm currently getting:
typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "dateOrdered", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here's my network request code:
func getOrders() async throws -> [Order] {
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(API.url)/orders/")!)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token!.value)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            // Make the request
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
        print(data)
        
        print(response)
            // Ensure we had a good response (status 200)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw GetOrdersError.unableToGetOrders
            }
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let orders = try decoder.decode([Order].self, from: data)
        
        print(orders)
        return orders
    }

Here's the Order model in my app:
struct Order: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id: UUID?
    var residentID: UUID
    var house: String
    var dateOrdered: Date
    var allPurposeCleaner: Bool
    var airFreshener: Bool
    var laundryPods: Bool
    var dishPods: Bool
    var dishSoap: Bool
    var windex: Bool
    var cloroxWipes: Bool
    var paperTowels: Bool
    var toiletPaper: Bool
    var toiletBowlCleaner: Bool
    var thrift: Bool
    var swifferPads: Bool
    var trashBags: Bool
    var isOrderCompleted: Bool
    
    static let houses = ["Wolf Pack", "Crow House", "Raptor House", "Lemur House", "Orca Pod", "Gorilla House", "Bison House", "Lion's Den"]
    
    
    init(id: UUID?, residentID: UUID, house: String, dateOrdered: Date, allPurposeCleaner: Bool, airFreshener: Bool, laundryPods: Bool, dishPods: Bool, dishSoap: Bool, windex: Bool, cloroxWipes: Bool, paperTowels: Bool, toiletPaper: Bool, toiletBowlCleaner: Bool, thrift: Bool, swifferPads: Bool, trashBags: Bool, isOrderCompleted: Bool) {
        
        self.id = id
        self.residentID = residentID
        self.house = house
        self.dateOrdered = dateOrdered
        self.allPurposeCleaner = allPurposeCleaner
        self.airFreshener = airFreshener
        self.laundryPods = laundryPods
        self.dishPods = dishPods
        self.dishSoap = dishSoap
        self.windex = windex
        self.cloroxWipes = cloroxWipes
        self.paperTowels = paperTowels
        self.toiletPaper = toiletPaper
        self.toiletBowlCleaner = toiletBowlCleaner
        self.thrift = thrift
        self.swifferPads = swifferPads
        self.trashBags = trashBags
        self.isOrderCompleted = isOrderCompleted
    }
}

Here's the Order model on my server:
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent

final class Order: Model, Content {
    
    init() {
    }
    
    static var schema: String = "orders"
    
    init(id: UUID, residentID: UUID, house: String, dateOrdered: Date, allPurposeCleaner: Bool, airFreshener: Bool, laundryPods: Bool, dishPods: Bool, dishSoap: Bool, windex: Bool, cloroxWipes: Bool, paperTowels: Bool, toiletPaper: Bool, toiletBowlCleaner: Bool, thrift: Bool, swifferPads: Bool, trashBags: Bool, isOrderCompleted: Bool) {
            
        self.id = id
        self.residentID = residentID
        self.house = house
        self.dateOrdered = dateOrdered
        self.allPurposeCleaner = allPurposeCleaner
        self.airFreshener = airFreshener
        self.laundryPods = laundryPods
        self.dishPods = dishPods
        self.dishSoap = dishSoap
        self.windex = windex
        self.cloroxWipes = cloroxWipes
        self.paperTowels = paperTowels
        self.toiletPaper = toiletPaper
        self.toiletBowlCleaner = toiletBowlCleaner
        self.thrift = thrift
        self.swifferPads = swifferPads
        self.trashBags = trashBags
        self.isOrderCompleted = isOrderCompleted
    }
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: "residentID")
    var residentID: UUID
    
    @Field(key: "house")
    var house: String
    
    @Field(key: "dateOrdered")
    var dateOrdered: Date
    
    @Field(key: "allPurposeCleaner")
    var allPurposeCleaner: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "airFreshener")
    var airFreshener: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "laundryPods")
    var laundryPods: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "dishPods")
    var dishPods: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "dishSoap")
    var dishSoap: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "windex")
    var windex: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "cloroxWipes")
    var cloroxWipes: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "paperTowels")
    var paperTowels: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "toiletPaper")
    var toiletPaper: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "toiletBowlCleaner")
    var toiletBowlCleaner: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "thrift")
    var thrift: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "swifferPads")
    var swifferPads: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "trashBags")
    var trashBags: Bool
    
    @Field(key: "isOrderCompleted")
    var isOrderCompleted: Bool
    
}

Here's Postman working fine:


Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the server. Have you done that?

replace your print(data) with print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)) and show us what you get from the server. The models you have must match the json data you get. You could try making dateOrdered a String, see if that works.
Alternatively, use a decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = ..., depending on your date format.

try this approach using a specific date decoder, adjust if your dates are not iso8601:
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601  // <-- here
  let orders = try decoder.decode([Order].self, from: data)

To use your own date format, use
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(myDateFormat)

